# Preg_match_all failing

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a preg_match_all pattern to catch only numbers with currency symbols, or if no symbol, just the number. But, it fails (returns nothing with no error) on anything but the $ symbol including no symbol.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html($url);

// Find price if added our code
$ret = $html->find('.price');

$pattern = '/\p{Sc}\s*\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?/u';
```

The following are examples of what might be returned by simple_html_dom and whether they work or fail - it could be ONE of the following

```
$ret[0] = '<span class="price">100</span>'; // this returns null

$ret[0] = '<span class="price">£100</span>'; // this returns null

$ret[0] = '<span class="price">€100</span>'; // this returns null

$ret[0] = '<span class="price">$100</span>'; // this works correctly and returns $100

preg_match_all($pattern, $ret[0], $matches);

echo $matches[0][0];
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: You appear to be using a DOM parser... Why do you later use regular expressions to parse HTML?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are replacing the `$ret` var, not putting strings in an array, so the regex matching will be performed only on the last string. If the one you posted is your code then you should make `$ret` an array and add the strings. [Here](http://rubular.com/r/tyTVkBEWFQ) everything seems to work fine in terms of regex!!

EDIT:
The problem I see now is that you are adding everything to `$ret[0]`, you should add to `$ret[0]` the first, `$ret[1]` the second and so on, or use `$ret[]=`

Comment: If this is your actual code check my updated answer. If instead you are managing arrays correctly I don't know

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do. In your code every string you put in `$ret[0]` overwrites the previous. If `$ret[0]` itself is an array you should add strings this way `$ret[0][]=`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20380/discussion-between-gabber-and-darren-sweeney)